# How To Calculate The Gibbs Energy Of A Molten Salt

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

If I have a molten salt of known composition, pressure, and temperature, is there a way to find the Gibbs energy of the substance?

I'm not talking about the change in gibbs energy, I mean H-TS

Comment: The thermodynamic functions of any number of salts have been determined and published. Did you have one in particular in mind, or are you looking for general references?

Comment: Are you talking about relative to the standard state at which the free energy of formation is specified?  Is the molten salt in equilibrium with pure vapor at the specified temperature and vapor pressure?

Answer (score 1):

Thermodynamic data for elements and many compounds has been collected for quite some time now. Values can be found in a number of reference works, such as "Thermochemical Properties of Inorganic Substances" (Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1991). Determining the Gibbs free energy of a pure substance or compound at a given temperature then consists of looking it up in the tables (or using the equation provided). The effects of pressure are often small.

Further, computer modeling of phase diagrams (Calculation of PHAse Diagrams - CALPHAD) is quite advanced at this point in time. As one example of work on salts (chosen for no reason other than it was a paper including NaCl on my hard drive) is [Phase equilibria in the reciprocal NaCl-KCl-NaNO3-KNO3 system](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0364591615300171?via%3Dihub), D. Sergeev et al., CALPHAD 51 (111-124) 2015. To quote the abstract:

> Differential thermal analysis of the various compositions in the KCl–NaNO3 and NaCl–KNO3 systems has been performed. Temperatures of phase transitions were obtained. The relative content of NaCl, KCl, NaNO3, and KNO3 compounds was determined by the use of X-ray diffraction analysis. These results
>   together with the experimental data from literature were used for optimization of thermodynamic parameters for all available phases and compounds to obtain the Gibbs energy data set which can be used for the calculation and prediction of the phase diagrams and other thermodynamic properties of these systems.

Such computer modeling tends to use Gibbs free energy data gathered and summarized by the [Scientific Group Thermodata Europe (SGTE)](http://sgte.net). Functional forms for the elements are found at [SGTE Data for Pure Elements](http://resource.npl.co.uk/mtdata/SGTEelementdata.pd). This information is also available if you use one of the several applications for phase diagram modeling such as [Thermocalc](http://www.thermocalc.com), [Pandat](http://www.computherm.com), or various other options.

Below is the KCl-NaCl phase diagram as calculated from the parameters in the Sergeev paper cited above:

[image: KCl-NaCl calculated phase diagram]